# Make [windows-universal] a synonym of [win-universal-app] or burninate it

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, synonym-request

Both tags: [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) and [windows-universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-universal) concern the same problems. Therefore I would suggest either to make [windows-universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-universal) a synonym or burninate it. What do you think?

Comment: It will take just 18 edits to eliminate `windows-universal`. Synonym and burnination is not required.

Comment: @slugster You are right. But IMO `windows-universal` is nice tag and I think if we rename those questions, then after a short time the tag will likely return. But I might be wrong, so I asked for opinion.

Comment: I stumbled about the same problem and was about to ask the same question here on Meta. Ignoring the problem hasn't improved the situation. Now windows-universal is used 400 times, win-universal-app 1000 times. Is there an agreement now what to do?

Comment: @stefan.s The tag synonym is [still waiting](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/win-universal-app/synonyms) for its votes to come. Four votes isn't that much, but taking into account that users rarely click tag-info and even more rarely click synonyms, makes it difficult to collect them - as for now 1 vote per year and I'm not sure if that isn't my vote :) In my opinion I would also make *windows-universal* the main tag, but seems like you cannot suggest a synonym that has more questions.

Comment: I wasn't even aware of tag synonym voting. So far I can't vote on this (I don't have the score yet).

Comment: @Romasz: Maybe you could answer your own question with a link to the tag to vote for the synonym?

Comment: @stefan.s I've written a small answer - maybe that will bring some attention. I also think that it may be a good idea to make it reverse way, but that will nees some edits - also not much, about 500, maybe little more and new voting. Let's see what community thinks, of course if it's interested in it.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like after a year [windows-universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-universal) is growing in questions and I think that along with realese of Windows 10 it will gain even more questions.

In my opinion the best would be [here a synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/247579). For those who aren't aware - [there is a voting running](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/win-universal-app/synonyms). Four votes isn't that much, but seems like most users don't visit *tag-info* and rarely click on *synonyms*.

Personally I would also make it inversely - make [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) a synonym of [windows-universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-universal), but that will need some tag edits to make [windows-universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-universal) having more questions than [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app). If you think it's a good idea, give me a sign.

Comment: Actually, at the time of my writing this comment (2015-09-01), [tag:win-universal-app] seems to have 146 followers and 1.1K questions, while the [tag:win-universal] that you see as growing has 69/463. Also, "windows-universal-app" sounds very clear, and "windows-universal" sounds very odd to me, like "windows-interesting" garbage tag or some library/framework from Universal studios. I wouldn't consider 'inverse' of that synonym to be a good idea. Oh, right.. there's the "win-universal-app" vs "windows-universal-app". I suppose it should be the latter!

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I see your point and you may be right that *windows-universal* may sound odd. As for me *windows-universal-app* seems to be little too long, I prefer shorter tags. Maybe we should consider *windows-uap*, like it's called in W10?

Comment: You're right, that turned out to be very long. Looking from this perspective,  `win-` prefix may be actually better. I can't make my mind regarding UAP. It's clear for those who got accustomed to that abbreviation, but for others it may be too confusing with UAC. `-uap` is still a great synonym to add to the family, but I'm not sure if I'd make it the root. But that's just my feeling, I don't want to sound authoritative :)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I also don't want to decide here and I'm glad it goes through discussion. I agree that `-uap` is as for now hard to understand for those who know nothing about it. I concur that `win-universal-app` is better for root than others, it's also intuitive.